# Умножение индексов, без создания новых c выводом по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Как решить задание, не сходиться с ответом (ответ не знаю). Мне кажется проблема в том, что не правильно отработал с индексами, наплодил много новых, а не изменил лишь имеющиеся сто.

Вот задание:

Возведите каждое значение серии в 3 степень, а значения индекса увеличьте в 3 раза.
Ответьте на следующие вопросы через запятую (без пробелов)

1. Выведите сумму элементов, строго меньших 2.6, имеющих нечётные значения индекса.
2. Выведите количество значений серии меньше нуля.

Так пробую решить:

```
np.random.seed(242)
    d = pd.Series(data = np.random.normal(size=100))
    n_i = np.arange(0,100)
    n_i = n_i*3
    d = d**3
    d1 = pd.Series(data = d, index = n_i)
    logical_results = (d1 < 2.6) & (d1.index % 2 != 0)
    print(np.sum(d1[logical_results]))
    logical_results = (d1 < 0)
    len(d1[logical_results])
    #ответ -0.23,17
```

Попробовал метод @MaxU ,но не сходиться с его ответом. В чем дело?

```
np.random.seed(242)
### Type your code here
d = pd.Series(data = np.random.normal(size=100))
d = d**3
d.index *= 3
print(d.loc[(d.index % 2 ) & (d < 2.6)].sum())
(d < 0).sum()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
# Возведите каждое значение серии в 3 степень
d = d**3
# значения индекса увеличьте в 3 раза
d.index *= 3
```

ответ 1:

```
In [19]: d.loc[(d.index % 2 != 0) & (d < 2.6)].sum()
Out[19]: -15.150748101821666
```

ответ 2:

```
In [143]: (d < 0).sum()
Out[143]: 51
```

---

**пояснения:**

`(d < 0)` - вернет серию значений типа `bool`. В Pandas, как и в Python, `True` - представлена значением `1`, `False` - значением `0`. Соответственно если просуммировать список / ndarray / pd.Series элементов с типом данных `bool` то получим число элементов со значением `True`.

Пример:

```
In [157]: np.array([False, False, False, True, True]).sum()
Out[157]: 2
```

Comment: В первый раз, вы взяли чётные , а во второй почему-то просуммировали(и сумма элементов оказалась равна из количеству, видимо я что-то пропустил в мат. статистике) Но это не суть, у меня в первом ответе действительно получилось другое число(во всех попытках отрицательное) и нормальные индексы, но проверить могу только завтра. Спасибо большое!

Comment: почему- то не сходиться. Исправил оригинал сообщения, там мой пример

Comment: -0.3655853964839706 это первый ответ. И второй раз как и у вас 51.

Comment: @АрсенГумин, а что получается так: `d.loc[(d.index % 2 != 0) & (d < 2.6)].sum()` ? PS похоже в новых версиях Pandas поменялось поведение и сейчас надо явно указывать `(d.index % 2 != 0)`

Comment: -15.150748101821671  Версия у меня 0.20.1

Comment: @АрсенГумин, посмотрите обновленный ответ - теперь результаты у нас совпадают

Comment: cпасибо, вы много где отвечаете про pandas и анализ данных, может заодно посоветуете литературу?)

Comment: @АрсенГумин, лично я изучал Pandas читая официальную документацию и отвечая на вопросы на SO ;)